# Can angular consume a decorated model with graphql functions

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, nestjs, apollo

I have a model in NestJs that decorated with Graphql functions

```
  @ObjectType()
  export class Companies {
    @Field(() => Int)
    public id: number;
  }
```

how can I share this model with angular

when refrence this model in angular I got this [error](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20819) :

> webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by
> default

I looking for best practices to shared models between backend and frontend,
there is a clean way?